# Derivative of inverse function where inverse is known only numerically.

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials, inverse

I have the following polynomial function in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x,a)=ax^3+x$$

However, $x$ also depends on $a$, so we should rather write:

$$f(x,a)=ax(a)^3+x(a)$$

Now I need derivative of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ **with respect to $a$**. The former is simple:

$${\partial\over \partial a}f'(x,a)=x^3+3x^2{\partial x\over\partial a}+{\partial x\over\partial a}$$

The inverse does not have simple analytical form, so I am trying to use inverse function theorem, i.e.:

$$(f^{-1})'(y)={1\over f'(f^{-1}(y))}$$

However, this works for single variable function, but the inverse is actually in two variables: $f^{-1}(y,a)$ ... I need however, just partial derivative of inverse w.r.t. $a$.

Please note that single root is assumed, therefore the inverse mapping is 1:1 and we don't need to care about multiple roots.

Comment: There is a version of the inverse function theorem for multiple variables.

Comment: I was looking for that without success (using keyword "multivariable inverse function theorem"). I found something called "implicit function theorem" but I am not sure if this is it nor how to apply it.

Comment: I just googled "inverse function theorem" (without multivariable) and got the wikipedia page which first states with the one variable version but then quickly gives also the multi variable version, with nice examples

Comment: I found it, thanks.

Comment: One problem is that it is impossible to compute $J^{-1}$ in this case because it is a non-square matrix ($1\times 2$).

Comment: Oh good point, a polynomial function $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is not going to have an inverse, even locally.

Comment: You may still find a one-sided inverse from $\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.  Meaning composition in one order will be the identity, but composition in the other order will not.

Comment: But I computed the inverse without problem numerically. I only need to compute it more precisely using some formula. Please note that I also care about partial derivative only (w.r.t. a), not in both variables (the x can be considered fixed). Such function can be plotted and I can see it has inverse (graphically), but I need the formula...

Comment: If $x$ is fixed then it is trivial since it is just a linear function in $a$.

Comment: I don't see how it's trivial. The forward derivative is already a third degree polynomial in $x$. The inverse can be computed only numerically so it seems I need a special numerical approximation routine for $f^{-1}(y,a)$ as $y$ depends on $a$ and we don't have the information on how it depends on it...

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is actually a function of single variable ($a$), even though it is composed of another function inside (which also depends on $a$). i.e. $x(a)$. Therefore the inverse function theorem applies.

I will write the function and its derivative compactly as:

$$\begin{align}y &= ax^3+x \\ y' &= x^3+3ax^2x'+x'\end{align}$$

Since we can compute $x$ from the first equation numerically, obtaining $x'$ from second equation is straightforward:

$$x'={y'-x^3 \over 3ax^2+1}$$